# Subversion and "protected/secure" files

Tags: svn

I have a requirement where certain code cannot be seen by all developers, but it's required for the full functional system.

So regular developers will be able to pull the main parts and authorized dev or manager will pull the rest and provide the artifact for the rest.

So for instance in SQL I have individual SQL files per SP. 2 of these SPs must be installed on the SQl server as encrypted SPs. The regular dev will pull and deploy everything but those 2 SPs and then the manager will pull the 2 SPs and install them for the dev.

There is very few cases like that in the project structure. So what is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting setup. I've seen where people are not allowed to commit to a repository, but very few where people are not even allowed to look at the files that it contains -- especially developers. There are a couple of suggestions:

- **Two Separate Repositories**: This keeps the *hidden* code more easily hidden. Building is a bit more difficult, but the security is simple: Users have access to the repository, or they don't.
- **Specifying Individual Directories**: You can specify who has read/write requirements upon individual directories. This must be handled via the front-end security access, and not pre-commit scripts. [Path-Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) is discussed in the Subversion manual. Word of warning: Any change in authorization requires you to restart your Subversion repository server. It all depends whether you're using `http://` or `svn://` as your repository server.

I highly recommend using a completely separate repository for the secret code.

Comment: Yep! Weird indeed! But sometimes you stuck with what you got! lol

Comment: I have to add... Think of it as a black box :) I work in a very secure environment and sometimes the less people now the better it is.